# random number sqlite iphone

Tags: xcode, ios, sqlite, random, arc4random

I'm trying to get a random number and match it up with a sqlite row.  So far I have:

```
number = (arc4random()%8)+1;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",number];
_label.text = string;
```

I'm confused on how I take this random number and match it with sqlite?  I'm trying to display "recipe.name".  Also, how could I incorporate "count" into this so that it limits the random number by the number of rows in the sqlite table?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to do that

```
int randumNumber = RandomNumber() % numberOFRows;
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I assign the random number to the respective sqlite column.  Also, is your "randomNumber" different than my "arc4random"?  Also, do I need to define "numberOFRows" before calling it?

Comment: Hi Benjamin, Your code must work properly, the maximum random number generated by this will be 8 only. So in your code instead of '8' give the number of recipes in your database.

Comment: Yes, I understand.  That is why I was wondering about the "count".  how do I assign the random number to the respective sqlite column so that the "recipe.name" is displayed and not the random number?

Comment: You need to read all of your recipes names into an array and get the names randomly.